# what are the mitigation techinique of CSRF vulnerability if:?

Tags: security, csrf, owasp, csrf-token, websecurity

if developer deny to implement the CSRF token. what alternative measures should developer make from the application point of view? (if browser security headers also not present. )

Comment: Authenticating user over JWT tokens in Authorization header helps.

Comment: yes it makes authorization more precise and secure, but what if JWT is stored?

Comment: The JWT token in the Authorization header needs to be always attached and it will not happen on its own unlike the cookies.